# Spartacus | Best practise to add some details in existing component where outletRef not available

Tags: spartacus-storefront

This question is more on best practise for including some more details in existing component where outlet ref is not available.

For ex. In checkout, during review-order step, I need to add some custom details with delivery-mode and i want to use the complete component as is.

Do i need to

- copy all the html & component logic from spartacus code
- create my custom component and use all copied code
- add the little detail with my delivery mode section
- replace the existing component by my custom component using COMPONENT as outlet-ref

There is lot of duplicate code to implement this.

Is there a better way like just inherit all the component detail by importing the component in my module and override the specific section (i am not sure but i was thinking that would be helpful. ).

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I would do:

- create new component
- copy all the html from spartacus to this component
- extend the original component instead of copying all the logic
- replace component in configuration

We're working on better way to extend templates, but that's not gonna be available soon. In the approach I recommended when updating spartacus you would only need to validate if the template changed, as the component logic will be automatically updated when you extend it.

Comment: Thanks @marcin . Yes, i was in thinking for something same now which is not perfect but  at least logic would be inherited. The best would be logic and html both would get inheritable.  It will work for now. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @marcin! Is there a ticket for extending the templates for me to keep track of the development? I am working a lot with Spartacus and this is a much needed feature imho.

Comment: Guys, do you know if the answer is still valid or if Spartacus has provided a better way of how to do it already?